# In season 2, how did Koichi manage to obtain Aoi Tsunemori's ear?

Tags: psycho-pass

**Note: The whole post is a spoiler.**

---

How did Koichi come to be in possession of [Aoi Tsunemori](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Aoi_Tsunemori)'s ear?

In Episode 9 of Psycho-Pass 2, [Koichi Kuwashima](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Koichi_Kuwashima) gave a present to [Akane Tsunemori](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Akane_Tsunemori) before turning himself over to MWPSB. That present was revealed to hold Aoi Tsunemori's ear.

Given the circumstances, I assumed that Koichi or [Kirito Kamui](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Kirito_Kamui) and company abducted Akane's grandmother, but given Akane's reaction I suppose Aoi wasn't killed up until that time.

However, earlier in the same episode  [Sakuya Togane](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Sakuya_Togane) ordered [Mika Shimotsuki](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Mika_Shimotsuki) to determine the whereabouts of Akane's grandmother. Also, in the scene next to Akane's reaction after seeing Aoi's ear, the expressions on Togane's face implied (as I saw fit) that he was involved in that brutal act.

In the last episode, Togane had revealed that he was the one behind the brutal killing of Aoi, whose body was found in Warehouse district (not sure whether it is the same district where she was living; an earlier episode revealed that she was living in a  nursing home with considerable drones guarding the place).

All of this doesn't seem to add up to a coherent plot.

- Kirito and company knew where Aoi was living and they were able to hack the drones guarding the place, as witnessed in an earlier episode.
- Togane came to know about Aoi's home via Mika.

Following are the two events that I suppose happened in the story but were not revealed and left to ponder:

- Koichi or friends stormed the house, took away Aoi's ear, and left off. Later, Togane came and killed Aoi brutally -- too many flaws in this plot.
- Alternatively, Togane first reached the house, killed Aoi and left the body in Warehouse district. Koichi or friends later visited the house or the place where the body was dumped, took away the ear, and went off -- I have high hopes with this theory.

There are some theories floating in some places on web that Togane and Koichi were working together, so after finishing off Aoi, Togane handed over her ear to Koichi since both had the intention to blacken Akane's hue. This doesn't follow any logic in my opinion since Koichi remained a loyal friend of Kirito, and Kirito and Togane were enemies.

So, what really happened? Or, what is the most logical conclusion for the story?

Comment: Togane wasn't involved in killing Tsunemori Aoi. It was done by Kirito's friends. He said that just to make Akane filled with murderous rage for revenge so that she will turn 'black' like he wanted.

Comment: I just checked the last episode again. Kunizuka said to Mika  that as per Kuwashima the person who leaked the location of Aoi was Togane, so my theory still holds here, i.e. Togane killed Aoi and Kirito and friends later picked up the body or at least the ear, unless I'm missing a sufficient evidence that Togane did not kill Aoi.

Comment: It's clear that Togane killed Tsunemori Aoi inside the car where she was held as hostage, after the ear was cut off (there's a scene after episode 9's ED). However, based on what I read somewhere, the timeline was: Mika found Aoi's home, Togane captured and cut her ear, Togane gave it to Koichi as a test to Akane (Kamui didn't approve it), Akane's psychopass wasn't affected, Togane killed Aoi. That's one theory I read.

Comment: Thanks @AkiTanaka, or should I call you Andrew T. :) I didn't know there was a scene after ending of Ep 9.  That changes the things significantly now. I just re-watched that episode. Your theory seems to be true. Kuwashima received a call when talking to Kirito near a door after massacring the officials, and he said after hanging up the call something like -- I was  skeptical about that information. That said, we just pulled out trump card. Considering the last scene after ED and Kirito's hesitance shown towards Kuwashima's plan, I guess your theory is true. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really happened, based on the evidence in the anime was:

1. [Intro] Togane really wanted to color Akane's Psycho-Pass black.
2. Togane told Mika to find where Akane's grandmother (Aoi) lived. The plan was to make Akane's playing role as Kamui's killer (by assuming that Kamui did *something bad* to Aoi, and Akane would take a revenge)
3. Togane knew that Koichi had a connection with Kamui when Yayoi were doing the investigation.
4. Koichi received a call, and after the call, he told Kamui that he had a doubt about the intel (possibly Togane), but they got their trump card (possibly Aoi's ear). However, Kamui didn't approve Koichi's plan since he believed that Akane's Psycho-Pass wouldn't be affected anyway. Koichi responded it as a test to Akane.
5. Akane and her team came, Koichi shown "the vision of hell" to them, and lastly before he gave in, he gave *a present* to Akane.
6. [Outro] Togane killed Aoi inside the car where she was held as hostage.

Actually, it wasn't clear *who* cut Aoi's ear. There are 3 possibilities:

1. Kamui knew the location in the first place and told Koichi.
2. After Mika found Aoi's location, Togane came, cut her ear, captured her and gave the ear to Koichi.
3. After Mika found Aoi's location, Togane told Koichi her location, and he did it instead of Togane.

The first one is impossible, based from Kamui's reaction to Koichi's plan. Second one is the most *believable*, judging from Togane's act & expression. But the third could be the the truth, based on Aoi's last word to Togane, "*Are you one of Akane's colleague?*", implying that she never encountered Togane before, and how the cut was taken care off, something that Togane could never do it (he *killed* anything).

Comment: I take it as the final word, unless a compelling and contradictory evidence (as an answer) emerges. Thanks for taking the time to answer. :)